# Is their any way to get some approximate figure, how much memory leaked in my program?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

To some extent I understand it's not feasible, because the system doesn't know if your programmer is keeping hold of some object intentionally or not.

But alternatively, can I see the list of objects and memory that has been allocated? This way I can see the name of those objects which are not intended to hold the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Flash Builder, you may profile an application to view current and cumulative instances and memory.  Large instance counts may be a sign of memory leaks:

[image: Flash Builder Profiler]

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have flash builder (with the profiler... its more expensive)

then you can use Monster Debugger or Stats... as an include in your code... very usefull
http://demonsterdebugger.com/
https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats
[image: Stats]

Comment: I'll throw in the caveat that these listed runtime memory monitors can *not* force garbage collection, and are dependent on the System.totalMemory property.  Without being able to force garbage collection, you can not truly know whether your application is leaking memory.  The Flash Player does not immediately release un-used memory chunks; it only sporadically removes them.  The Flash Builder IDE mentioned by Jason Sturges does allow you to force garbage collection.

Comment: the new debug flash player has a method to force garbage collection:  System.gc()

Comment: Cool! Thanks for letting me know -- I was not aware of that.